# Jupyter Notebook: overwrite output cell during loop instead of outputting in append

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, output

This question is different from others because I need the output cell to be overwritten and updated many times throughout the process, instead, other questions just care about outputting the final value when the entire loop completes.

### Problem

I am executing some actions within a loop and every 100th iteration I need to track the update of the process using a visualization (plotly). The problem is that instead of keeping only one plot in the output cell, they are accumulated and soon I need to scroll down 20 pages to find the latest plot in the output cell.

### Example

For the sake of simplicity, in this question let's assume I just want to visualize some text.

```
for i in range(10000):
    if i%100 == 0:
        print('This is an update for iteration number {:d}'.format(i))
```

### Expected solution

Instead of visualizing in the cell:

```
100
200
300
...
```

I would like the output cell to be overwritten every time a new output is visualized throughout the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [IPython.display.clear_output](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.clear_output) to clear the output of a cell:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

for i in range(1000000000):
  if i % 100000 == 0:
    clear_output()
    print('This is an update for iteration number {:d}'.format(i))
    df = px.data.iris()
    fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species",
                    size='petal_length', hover_data=['petal_width'])
    fig.update_layout(title='i')

    fig.show()
    time.sleep(15)   # add this to allow the plot visualization
```